# GCP console Listagem de Todas subnets em uso

Tags: python

Tenho alguns projetos rodando no GCP mas pelas politicas da empresa preciso incluir todas subnets que estão sendo utilizadas na firewall.

estou utilizando python para processar as respostas dos comandos do cgp e organizar os dados.

primeiro listo todos projetos:

```
gcloud projects list --format=json
```

depois falo um laço para cada projeto usar este comando:

```
gcloud compute networks subnets list --project PROJECT_ID --format=json
```

tenho 2 problemas:

1- se não tenho acesso ao projeto ele mostra na tela essa mensagem:

```
API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [999999999]. Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? (y/N)?
```

como não tenho acesso ao projeto em questão como faço para o python quando detectar isso de um `N` e pule para o proximo projeto?

meu comando de python para fazer o bash é este:

```
args = shlex.split("gcloud compute networks subnets list --project PROJECT_ID --format=json")
cli_input = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = cli_input.communicate()
ret = output.decode('utf-8'), error
```

Minha dúvida principal é como detectar essa solicitação do google quando consulto um projeto e fazer com que o python responda um `N` e pular para o scam do proximo projeto.

Comment: Duas possibilidades aqui, recomendaria pensar nisso: se a dúvida for sobre o google-cloud não está no escopo (até removi as tags, não faz sentido neste momento, até para evitar atrair perguntas de infraestrutura que deveriam ser do [devops.se]). Agora, se for a questão do parse via Python, ai sim, claramente de programação, mas aí seria melhor tirar o excesso de informação sobre a parte google-cloud e focar no [mcve] do parse dos dados já processados (senão vira um suporte de google-cloud "disfarçado" de programação, mesmo que não seja intencional).

Comment: meu principal problema é o 1 mesmo pois o google fica esperando uma resposta e se dou S ou N ele da erro no cod. teria que ter uma forma de detectar isso e pular o projeto que m solicita acesso.

Comment: Se o problema é o y/N você poderia editar a pergunta, criar um cenário seguindo o [mcve] focando no problema sobre 'inputar' informações solicitadas, independente do GPC, focado apenas no controle do stdin e stdout para determinar o que fazer. Recomendo [edit] e eliminar toda a parte desnecessária. É possivel simular um comando com bash ou bat (em windows) que seria executado com subprocess para checar o y/n. Sobre o erro 2 da pergunta, me parece totalmente off, já que a resolução estaria relacionada ao comando de linha ou terceiros, nesse caso pode tentar a sugestão do @Bacco

Comment: Apenas por enquanto estou fechando, assim que [edit] focando apenas no problema de programação (detectar o y/n e 'inputar' a resposta) sua pergunta será avaliada por diferentes usuários na [fila de análises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reviews-intro) e poderá ser reaberta se atender aos critérios do [mcve] e [help/on-topic]. Obrigado por compreender.